# The superclass 'Bloc<xxx, xxx>' doesn't have a zero argument constructor in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-state

I am a beginner in Dart language development. I try to create a sample flutter application BLOC pattern inspired by [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/newajthevillager/FirebaseUserAuthentication---BLoC), but I got some error message related to the class inheritance. I am already familiar with the inheritance and superclass and subclass programming in the dot net C# language. But in the case of the dart, I need some advice.

Here is my code:

```
class UserRegBloc extends Bloc<UserRegEvent, UserRegState> {
  UserRepository userRepository;

   UserRegBloc({@required UserRepository userRepository}) {
   userRepository = UserRepository();
}

@override
UserRegState get initialState => UserRegInitial();

 @override
 Stream<UserRegState> mapEventToState(UserRegEvent event) async* {
   if (event is SignUpButtonPressed) {
     yield UserRegLoading();
       try {
      var user = await userRepository.signUpUserWithEmailPass(
        event.email, event.password);
    print("BLOC : ${user.email}");
    yield UserRegSuccessful(user: user);
  } catch (e) {
    yield UserRegFailure(message: e.toString());
    }
  }
 }
}
```

[image]

### Edit

My pubspec.yaml dependencies are below:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you need to provide an initial state to the bloc. Something like this:

```
class UserRegBloc extends Bloc<UserRegEvent, UserRegState> {
  UserRepository userRepository;

   UserRegBloc({@required UserRepository userRepository}) : super(UserRegInitialState()) {
       userRepository = UserRepository();
   }
   // ...
}
```

where `UserRegInitialState` is a subclass of `UserRegState`.

This is the difference due to different versions of the bloc library. Your link project uses flutter_bloc version 3.0 and the version of the same package in your question is 6.1.1. So there is a small difference in code. The error, basically, tells that the base class of `UserRegBloc` requires one parameter. So you couldn't declare a subclass without providing that parameter, thus the error.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ya, I noticed this error not appear in the older version of the bloc library.

Comment: I am just adopting the structure of the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the constructor (instance variable) of the superclass.