# Flutter npm flutter_bloc migration to 6.1.1

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a question if somoneone know how to make the migration to flutter_bloc 0.6, to 6.1, because I updated the version and now is all givin errors, if someone know how to do it or a bit explanation or some link to migration do it, will be great, thanks.

Some Errors:

- The method 'dispatch' isn't defined for the type 'TabsBloc'.
- The superclass 'Bloc<ThemeEvent, ThemeState>' doesn't have a zero argument constructor.
- The named parameter 'builder' isn't defined.
- The method 'dispose' isn't defined for the type 'ThemeBloc'.

Comment: I would suggest that you slowly upgrade your flutter_bloc version so that you can gradually fix its errors. Sample, 0.6.0 -> 0.7.0, if no errors, upgrade again.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64954284/the-superclass-blocxxx-xxx-doesnt-have-a-zero-argument-constructor-in-dart

Comment: not working hehe i found some solutions

Answer (score 3):

Solutions:

- 'dispatch' on bloc updated to 'add'.
- 'get initialState => InitialState()' updated to ': super(InitialState())' on constructor bloc class.
- 'Builder' on bloc updated to 'Create'.
- 'Dispose' on bloc updated to 'Close'.